# populate input field with PHP variable

Tags: php

I am creating a pizza ordering site with php. Now I want to echo the variable passed through the URL within the form. I know how to retrieve this data: `<?php echo $_GET["numpizzas"]; ?>`. But I don't know the proper way to add it to my html form field. any help is much appreciated

```
<?php

echo 
'<form action="pizza.php" method="post">
<h1>Thanks for Ordering. Please submit your delivery info.</h1>
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">
<label>Address:</label> <input type="text" name="address">
<label>Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone">
<label>Money: </label><input type="text" name="money" value="<?php echo "hi"; ?>" >
//Money field does not populate with number, I just see <?php echo $_GET[ 
<label>Feedback:</label> <input type="text" name="feedback">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';

?>
<?php echo $_GET["numpizzas"]; ?>
```

I also tried storing the integer in a variable `$howmanypizzas = $_GET["numpizzas"]; ?>`but it still doesn't show up as the field value.

Comment: yes the page is php extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php echo $_GET["numpizzas"]; ?>` does not only retrieve the data. `echo` also outputs it to the html response (the screen)

since you are allready passing your html with an ECHO, you can do:

```
<?php

echo 
'<form action="pizza.php" method="post">
<h1>Thanks for Ordering. Please submit your delivery info.</h1>
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">
<label>Address:</label> <input type="text" name="address">
<label>Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone">
<label>Money: </label><input type="text" name="money" value="'.$_GET["numpizzas"].'" >
<label>Feedback:</label> <input type="text" name="feedback">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';

?>
```

Explanation: echo is a function that recieves a string and outputs it to html.
So, with the concatenation operator `.` you can inject the `$_GET["numpizzas"]` variable into your html, as a string, and pass it to the echo function, wich outputs it to the browser.
Another way to solve it is to only invoke PHP where you need to process your logic, just like @pavithra answer, wich also works.

Answer (score 1):

You're already echoing and trying to echo inside of that.  You need to concatenate your variable with the string that you are echoing, see [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
echo 
'<form action="pizza.php" method="post">
<h1>Thanks for Ordering. Please submit your delivery info.</h1>
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">
<label>Address:</label> <input type="text" name="address">
<label>Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone">
<label>Money: </label><input type="text" name="money" value="' . $_GET["numpizzas"] . '">
<label>Feedback:</label> <input type="text" name="feedback">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';
```

You might also consider [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="money" value="<?php echo $_GET["numpizzas"]; ?>" />
```

but i dont get why do you get this is as a get variable.hope this works

```
<form action="pizza.php" method="post">
   <h1>Thanks for Ordering. Please submit your delivery info.</h1>
   <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">
   <label>Address:</label> <input type="text" name="address">
   <label>Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone">
   <label>Money: </label> <input type="text" name="money" value="<?php echo $_GET["numpizzas"]; ?>" />

   <label>Feedback:</label> <input type="text" name="feedback">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```